# Change the color of the "margins" on Alert Buttons

Tags: android, margin, android-alertdialog

How do I change the color of the margins that separates the Alert Buttons (Positive and Negative)?

This is what I want to change:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zSsgH.jpg

(Cant freaking upload images due to rep)

Thanks!

**EDIT**

What I have now is:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#80000000"
>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center|bottom"
    android:layout_margin="10dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="100px"
        android:layout_height="100px"
        android:src="@drawable/more_info_icon"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="More Information"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="20dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/alert_dialog_text_1"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/alert_margin"
    android:textColor="#000000"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/alert_dialog_text_2"
    android:layout_marginBottom="11dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"/>
```

and

```
builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_alert_dialog, null));
builder.setPositiveButton(...);
builder.setNegativeButton(...);
Button negB = ((AlertDialog) dialog).getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE);
Button posB = ((AlertDialog) dialog).getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
negB.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#80000000"));
posB.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#80000000"));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant change the margin color, but what you can do is wrap the contents in a new linear layout and change the background color of that!

[here is an example:](http://i.gyazo.com/cc9d40b111a88b1233be1a7a08e68a1f.png)

btw the shadows on the buttons wont appear when you run the app.

and the code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="#fff">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ffff0000"

        >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:background="#000"
            android:text="BUTTON1"
            android:textColor="#fff" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:background="#000"
            android:text="BUTTON2"
            android:textColor="#fff" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Just to be sure, this way I can't use the .setPositiveButton and .setNegativeButton, or can I?

If I can, how do I do it? The margins are showing because it is added buttons. They are not on the original Layout file

Comment: you would change the linear layout color

Comment: I will update my question to show what I already have... I believe that I couldn't really explain it.

Comment: im sorry i didnt understand what your question was at first... i still dont think there is a way to do this, but there might be

Comment: No worries... I think that the easiest way would be to simply set the buttons as a layout structure. Although I still want to know how to do it programatically